# django returns more objects than it should

Tags: python, django

My problem is related to getting the one instance of the model. The filtering condition I give is unique and I should receive only one instance. It returns 7 instead (all of them).

Model:

```
class Movie_dates(models.Model): #// signals appended - Creates this model straight after new Movie has been added
    main_movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    time = models.ManyToManyField(Hours)
```

This model is being created automatically (x7) after creating the main model. Date field is incremented datetime.now() + timedelta.days(i)

And my views:

```
if request.session.get("user_choice"):
        user_choice = request.session.pop("user_choice")
        movie_date = user_choice["date"]
        movie_hour = user_choice["hour"]

        movie = Movies.objects.get(pk=pk)
        dates = Movie_dates.objects.get(main_movie=movie, date=datetime.strptime(str(movie_date), "%Y-%M-%d").date())
```

The user_choice content is visible in my views and for sure it's been converted to date format. I still receive all of the objects instead of the only one with particular date provided. Appreciate for help.

Issue resolved. I have changed few things in my code and worked :)

Comment: You've not got a 1-to-1 relationship between a movie & dates, so there could well be many dates for a movie. Unless you have `unique_together = ('main_movie', 'date')` on your `Movie_dates` class?

Comment: still does the same :(

Comment: Well yeah, the objects still exist. What you've done doesn't create a unique relationship so you can't use `get()`

Comment: Is an exception thrown? If not how do you know you are getting 7 dates? You are using ```objects.get``` and this can only return one instance. If multiple instances are found an exception is raised.

Comment: I receive error that 7 objects have been  created instead. Movie_dates is generated with post_save signal.

Comment: This means these rows do have the same date value. Please show the code generating these values - the problem is most likely there.